# What's wrong with this approach for finding expected number of throws before 2 identical throws?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, dice

I am trying to find the expected number of throws before a die shows up the same twice in a row.

The definition of expected value is $$E(n) = \sum_nnP(n)$$

I have seen other answers elsewhere on how to solve this problem, but my approach is thus:

Succeeding on the $n^{th}$ throw requires that you failed on the $(n-1)^{th}$ throw. So it makes sense that $$P(n) = \frac{1}{6}(1-P(n-1))$$ since, after $n-1$ throws, you must roll what was rolled on the $(n-1)^{th}$ throw, and there is a $1/6$ chance of that. Having Wolfram do the heavy lifting with $P(2) = 1/6$ I get $$P(n) = \frac{1}{7}(-\frac{1}{6})^n((-6)^n+6)$$

So it seems to me that $$E(n) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty nP(n)$$ but, apparently, this is divergent. So what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: The answer will be $7$.  The first throw cannot trigger the end, but from then on each throw has a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance to match the throw previous regardless what it happened to be and so this becomes effectively the same as trying to calculate the expected number of throws until rolling a $1$ (*after taking the off-by-one error into account*).

Comment: Okay, thank you for the comment. But I am not only interested in the answer; I am also interested in why my approach doesn't work. Can you shed light on that?

Comment: The probability that your *first* success occurs on the $n$'th throw is $\frac{1}{6}$ (*the probability that the $n$'th throw matched the $n-1$'st*) times the probability that the first $n-1$ attempts were all failures.  Note that the probability that the first $n-1$ attempts are all failures is *not* the same thing as $1$ minus the probability that the $n-1$'st throw is the first success.  Instead $1-P(n-1)$ also includes in it the chance that the first success occurred within the earlier attempts before the $n-1$'st throw.

Comment: Rather, for $n>1$ you have $P(n) = \frac{1}{6}\times \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-2}$

Comment: Perfect sense. Perhaps you should make this an answer?